# Rails 3.2 - Unable to load modules of initializers files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

### Environment

- Ruby **[1.9.3p547]**
- Rails **[3.2.22.5]**
- Devise **[3.0.4]**

When i run any rails or rake command for this application it is giving me below error

> /config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': undefined
>   method`setup' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)

If i comment file devise.rb and run rails command again.

> /config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb:1:in `':
>   uninitialized constant Doorkeeper (NameError)

And so on if i comment doorkeeper.rb file it is giving me error for

> /config/initializers/kaminari_config.rb:1:in `':
>   uninitialized constant Kaminari (NameError)

i can't get what is issue with my application i am unable to perform any rake or rails. its directly giving me error of uninitialized constant .

The ruby and rails version is very old. I don't want to upgrade it. Earlier i though it was issue of devise gem. but it must not be issue of devise gem.

Please help me if any one has idea about this type of error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some installation issues. Please try to install from scratch.
Follow these steps.

1. Find version of bundler from `Gemfile.lock`
2. Install bundler with that version and continue with bundle install
3. Check for API_KEY and values in your initializers.
4. Check for Gem support for your Ruby version (as it is too old)